# PHP: How can be html tags replaced with " "?

Tags: php, regex

PHP: How can I replace HTML-tags replaced with " "?

With the following code:

```
$str = 'line1<div>line2</div>line3';
echo strip_tags($str);
```

I get

```
line1line2line3
```

But expected result is

```
line1 line2 line3
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$result = preg_replace('/<.+>/U', ' ', $str);`

Comment: Replace with `' '`, a single space. You might want to use a `+` quantifier instead of a `*` quantifier too in case OP wants to keep `<>`.

Comment: Revised regexp a bit in light of comment + question revision. Thanks :)

Comment: Note that `>` is allowed in attribute values.

Answer (score 1):

```
$rxtags = '
<(?:
    (?: (?: (?:script|style) \s* | (?:script|style) \s+ (?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+\s* ) > .*? </(?:script|style)\s* )
  | (?: /?\w+\s*/? | \w+\s+ (?:".*?"|\'.*?\'|[^>]*?)+\s*/? | !(?:DOCTYPE.*?|--.*?--) )
 )>
';

$html = 'line1<div>line2</div>line3';
$html =~ s/$rxtags/ /xsg;
print $html,"\n";
```

Output: `line1 line2 line3`

Comment: why just not preg_replace('/<.+>/U', ' ', $str);?

Comment: @Yosef, on a substantial sample there is a %99 chance my regex will **only** strip markup tags. There is a %100 chance `<.+?>` will not.